# How to install a .exe file in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I have an editor which has .exe format and i want to install it on Ubuntu 16.04. How it is possible to install this application in Ubuntu?

Comment: You must download wine software then you will able to run .exe app [enter link description here]
https://youtu.be/2KQT6e6peng
Or https://youtu.be/1me6ebGWKEo

Comment: hi i have installed wine and i have able to install some .exe application ,but when i try to install a editor which is also .exe file it shows the error  directory name invalid.

Comment: Which editor are you installing

Comment: it is same like notepad but some extra features added by a private company for its personal use and it has  .exe file

Comment: @SantoshBhagwat Try using a directory name without any spaces

Comment: @NickWeinberg    sorry but i can't understand what you say. whenever i try to install by right click on that exe file and open with wine windows program loader that time it shows me error like directory name invalid, i don't no which directory.